# CSS in <body> part (without inline)

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to put some CSS into the BODY part of my html page without using inline CSS?
e.g.: I want to make all  elements of one table red. Downside here: need same style=".." for every TD.

```
<table>
<tr>
<td style="background-color:#f00">RED</td>
<td style="background-color:#f00">RED</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason why it must be in the BODY?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To keep all the code within the body you could use javascript to first find all TD's then apply the background color:

```
<script>
        var cells = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
        for (var i=0; i<cells.length; i++) {
            cells[i].style.backgroundColor = '#c0c0c0';
        }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks. So what i am trying to do is not achieved by regular use of CSS i guess.

Comment: Not if you don't want to add the CSS in the HEAD. If you are locked out of the head, as with some CMS, then you are limited to either inline styles on each element, or using javascript.  If you do have access to the HEAD, that is certainly preferred.

Answer (score 6):

If you want all 'td' elements of one specific table with a specific css style, you should use this code:

html:

```
<table id="tableOne">
    <tr>
        <td>red background</td>
        <td>red background</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>blank background</td>
        <td>blank background</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

css:

```
#tableOne td{
    background-color: #FF0000;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<table class="myClass">
   <tr>
     <td>RED</td>
     <td>RED</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

And your css class **myClass**:

```
.myClass td
{
   background: #F00;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In an embedded or external style sheet:

```
td { background: #F00; }
```

That's all.

Comment: @user - is that a problem? Why do you want to put it inside the body?

Comment: Embedded, yes; but you could also use a linked stylesheet, so that the head would contain `<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" />` linking to your stylesheet.

Comment: Let's say i only want this particular table to be red. So i don't want to put it into the .css file just for this one table.

Comment: @user763267, you should put into your .css file just for that single table. 
Try separating your css from your html code. It will help you a lot.

Comment: OK. thanks. so inline,external & embedded are the only options for css, I've learned that.

Comment: @Karl If you want to limit to that table, assign the table an ID then select the table by ID.  The html would be something like `<table id="red-table">`, and the css would be `#red-table td { background #F00; }`.  Look up info on ID selectors, class selectors, and descendant selectors.  A thorough understanding of those will make your life a lot easier.